# Css html full bleed and centering

Tags: html, css, center

I am trying to learn html/css from scratch  and have started a small project. I have researched these topics here but i find it a bit advanced and was hoping someone could explain it to me step by step so i might learn something from it :)

Challenge 1:
I am trying to get full bleed color vertically. The thing is that i get a white frame around the color areas. I have used the code below to get it to go edge to edge on the left side and top.

```
margin-right: -8px;
margin-top: -8px;
```

But it wont go all the way to the edge on the right side.
Ill post my html and css below. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

```
HTML
<div id="feature1">
<div id="feature1_cont">Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div>
</div>

CSS
#feature1 { 
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
background-color: #0CC;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-right: -8px;

}

#feature1_cont {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:36px;
margin-top: 7%;
margin-left: 7%;
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 600px;
background-color: #0F9;

}
```

Challenge 2:
I also have 3 divs inside a div. I would like to center them so that that move and are always in the center. But i can only get them to stay left. The code is below

```
CSS
#feature2 { 
width: 100%;
heigt: 100%;
float: left;
background-color: #C96;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-right: -8px;

}

#feature2_cont {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #36F;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
float: left;

}


HTML
<div id="feature2">
<div id="feature2_cont">Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div>
<div id="feature2_cont">Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div>
<div id="feature2_cont">Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use `padding: 8px` on the body?

Comment: I have tried Padding but this extends the aerea of color on the div. So that instead of being X*X pixels of color, it becomes X*X+padding pixels of color. Also, i dont yet understand all the difference of it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Chalenge 1:**

Remove the negative margin on `#feature1` and add `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` to the top of your css

**Chalenge 2:**

remove `float: left;` and add `margin: 0 auto;` to `#feature2_cont`

Comment: Chalenge 1 is solved :) Could you tell me what i just did there?
Chalenge 2: This just took away all the spacing and left adjusted them. Did i miss something?

Comment: When adding styles to `*` you are targeting all elements. Browsers have default styles for all elements and some of the styles include padding and margin. Removing padding and margin on all elements allows you to add your desired amount of padding and margin. A good way to avoid tripping over browser styles is to add a CSS reset to your page. [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Thanks Eric! Got any more tips to center those divs?

Comment: Ahh, cool. Is it possible to get these to be on a horisontal line instead of vertical? Ive been googleing but can quite get to grips with it :)